# Laptop powers off automatically : Ubuntu 18.04 & Jupyter Notebook running Python 2

Tags: 18.04, jupyter

My laptop (HP Elitebook 840 G5) just powers off, in the middle of using Jupyter Notebook (running/editing python scripts). Every time I had do a hard reset of the laptop to boot it back on.
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 dual booted with Win 10. This problem is observed only when using Juypter Notebook on ubuntu.
If you need any additional info, do comment.
Please provide your suggestions to find the bug?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have a "poweroff without warning" feature...but your laptop's hardware does. Note the exact time of a poweroff, then check /var/log/syslog for errors in the minute before that time. If there are errors in the log, post them. If there are no errors in the log, then you have faulty hardware.

Answer (score 0):

See this post for an example of investigating errors: [jupyter notebook crash](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3602)

To see the messages you need to start `jupyter` from the command line:

```
jupyter notebook
```

At the end of the link notice what the author did to prevent crashing:

```
mkdir /run/user/1000/jupyter
```

---

Here is a [Redhat Linux](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1542976) question & answer with a different `jupyter` crash log.

If you are still having problems after trying solutions then edit your question and put the crash log into it.